# How to create a Custom Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, quickview, pdp

We are working on the Product Quick View option on the Category page. We need to load the product details on a popup. How can we get all the product details kinda a duplicate PDP layout? We dont need to load the Original PDP layout (catalog_product_view.xml), it renders the whole page again in the popup.

Comment: you can go with available free module https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-quick-view-extension.html

Comment: Thanks @Pawan. But this extension too rendering the core PDP layout file with js and css for the Quick View.

Comment: agree with you...